# Grails Issue with ShoppingCart plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to use the Grails shopping cart plugin found here: http://grails.org/plugin/shopping-cart

I was able to successfully install the plugin in my application, as well as inject the service in my Controller:

```
class TestController {
def shoppingCartService

def index() {

    def s = new DomainObj(name: "A Plain Ole Domain Object")
    s.addToShoppingCart()
 }
}
```

This appears to be adding the product to my shopping cart, as I expected. However, the problem I'm encountering now is actually listing the items out from the cart. According to the debugger, after running the above code, the shopping cart does indeed have an item (s) in it, as it returns:

`com.metasieve.shoppingcart.ShoppingItem : 1`

The item is properly being added to the cart, but now I would like to actually list the name of the item out again, so in this case, I want to display the name `A Plain Ole Domain Object`. How do I do this?

I'm unsure of the syntax for getting the actual objects back from the cart. The documentation doesn't describe how to do this clearly, as it merely states that the following should work:

```
def checkedOutItems = shoppingCartService.checkOut()

checkedOutItems.each { 
println it['item'] 
println it['qty'] 
}
```

But that outputs 
`com.metasieve.shoppingcart.ShoppingItem : 1` , which is only a reference to some arbitrary item in the cart. I want to get back the actual name of my item.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My domain class (DomainObj) is defined as follows:

```
class DomainObj extends com.metasieve.shoppingcart.Shoppable {
String name

static constraints = {
name blank: false
}
}
```

EDIT #2:

```
def index() {

    def s = new DomainObj(name: "A Plain Ole Domain Object")
    s.addToShoppingCart()
    def r = new DomainObj(name: "Second Plain Ole Domain Object")
    r.addToShoppingCart()

    def checkedOutItems = shoppingCartService.checkOut()


   println currentItems
    println "-----"

    checkedOutItems.each {
        println it['item']
        println it['qty']
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

`[com.metasieve.shoppingcart.ShoppingItem : 1, com.metasieve.shoppingcart.ShoppingItem : 2]`

`com.metasieve.shoppingcart.ShoppingItem : 2`

`1`

`com.metasieve.shoppingcart.ShoppingItem : 1`

`1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation it["item"] gives you back the entity of a domain class that extends Shoppable. So in this case when you are printing it out it's calling the toString() method of that domain class. If you want that to return the value of the name property you need to implement your own toString(). Here is such an example

```
@Override
String toString() {
  return name
}
```

EDIT:
Well as it's not clear from the documentation it['item'] is a pointer to the Shoppable instance which you can then use to query for the actual product in your cart like this:

```
com.metasieve.shoppingcart.Shoppable.findByShoppingItem(it['item'])
```

Thus the following will print out the toString() value of your products

```
checkedOutItems.each {
  println com.metasieve.shoppingcart.Shoppable.findByShoppingItem(it['item'])
  println it['qty']
}
```

For testing I created the following domain and controller.

Domain:

```
package com.test

class MyProduct extends com.metasieve.shoppingcart.Shoppable {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false)
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        return name
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.test

class MyProductController {

    def shoppingCartService

    def index() { 
        def p1 = new MyProduct(name: 'one')
        p1.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        p1.addToShoppingCart()
        def p2 = new MyProduct(name: 'two')
        p2.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        p2.addToShoppingCart()

        def checkedOutItems = shoppingCartService.checkOut()
        checkedOutItems.each {
           println com.metasieve.shoppingcart.Shoppable.findByShoppingItem(it['item'])
           println it['qty']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Joshua, Thanks for the reply. I tried this, by adding the @Override String toString() returning the name, as you have included above. It didn't seem to have an effect on the output though. For the print it['item'] it still shows `com.metasieve.shoppingcart.ShoppingItem` : <shopping_item_id> ` .

Comment: @meoww- Your domain class does extend com.metasieve.shoppingcart.Shoppable right?

Comment: Hi Joshua, Thanks again. Yes, my domain class does extend Shoppable. I edited the question so that you can see my domain. Thanks for trying to work through this with me.

Comment: @meoww- No worries. I'm poking around in the source code and everything you have seems to be exactly like the example/test product: http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-shopping-cart/trunk/grails-app/domain/com/metasieve/shoppingcart/ShoppingCartTestProduct.groovy on the off chance, have you tried a grails clean?

Comment: Hi Joshua, Thanks again. I tried grails clean just now. I also added a second object, just to see what would happen. I now am seeing the text `[com.metasieve.shoppingcart.ShoppingItem : 1, com.metasieve.shoppingcart.ShoppingItem : 2]` I ensured that the @Override String toString() method still exists too. No luck so far. Hrm.

Comment: @meoww- That would somehow indicate a collection. Is that what's printing for it["item"]?

Comment: Hi Joshua, I updated my question with Edit #2, to show my entire index action of the controller. I also updated the total outputs to my console now...If that helps?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45666/discussion-between-joshua-moore-and-meoww)